# Запятая при приложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении после слова комиссии:

> Председатель комиссии заместитель
> администрации района ? подвел итоги
> проведенной тренировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Председатель комиссии заместитель **председателя** администрации района **И. И. Иванов**  подвел итоги проведенной тренировки.*

Comment: В данном случае председатель комиссии заместитель главы администрации района... Значит, без запятых?

Comment: Я бы запятую не ставил, хоть без неё читается и несколько тяжеловато.

Может, несколько перестроить предложение?

К примеру, так:

Председатель комиссии И. И. Иванов -- заместитель главы администрации района -- подвел итоги проведенной тренировки.

Comment: Спасибо, я,наверное, так и сделаю